# How to set JSP page encoding using Servlet 3.0 annotation configuration (or Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I recently converted my XML-based configuration to pure annotation (using a mixture of javax.servlet.annotation and Springframework classes). One thing I haven’t figured out how to configure is this:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Rick. Had you found the solution?

Comment: Gosh, that was so long ago, I don't even remember.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same problem here.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
```

in every JSP fixes the issue.

Still looking for a better way to handle this, though.